# Overlay Floating Button in Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, overlay

I have a layout like this:

[image]

But as you can see, the Floating Button is not overlaying the edit text. Is there any way to do this in `LinearLayout`? (I cannot use other layouts).

I have seen many answer on SO but all of them use either `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`.

Here is my xml (the floating button is at the end) -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />

    <!--Overlay this image -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I want it to look -

[image]

Comment: there's a reason all of the other answers use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. LinearLayout is as named, Linear. It doesn't support layers. Please use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as in one the other answers you read.

Comment: use frame layout to achieve this

Comment: You cant do that what you desire with using only linearlayout, you have to use framelayout for that

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` like the below code:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"/>
</FrameLayout>
```